# flutter how sync mysql to sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, synchronization, sqflite

I have a similar issue with the two-way sync between flutter "android"
'ios' sqflite and MySql DB centralized. The problem really comes when making the inserts, because it admits that the primary keys can be duplicated. Is the solution in tables sqflite  or tables Mysql

Comment: Primary keys cannot be duplicated neither in mysql nor in sqlite. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: You could generate unique random tokens instead and use those as identifiers instead of the auto generated sequential primary keys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.